# Getting an object rather than the desired attribute in DJango

Tags: python, django

I am trying to append ids of objects from a particular model into a list but am unable to do so:

Error:

```
Field 'unq_id' expected a number but got <main: main object (8)>.
```

Views.py:

```
def experts(request):
    if 'post' in request.session:
        del request.session['post']
        print("del")
    cat = categories.objects.all()
    list2 = []
    testlist = []
    testlist2= []
    listforexpid = []
    exp = Expert.objects.all() 

    for objects in exp:
        testlist.append(objects.unq_id)
        listforexpid.append(objects.e_id)
        print(objects.e_id)
    for obj in testlist:
        
        a = main.objects.get(unq_id = obj)  
        testlist2.append(a.first_name)

    for x in exp:
        list2.append(x.image.url)
    
    for obj in exp:     
        exp_name =  main.objects.values_list('first_name')
        unq_id =  main.objects.values_list('unq_id')

        
        
    c = zip(list2,testlist2,listforexpid)
    
    return render(request, 'Main/experts.html', {'exp':exp, 'list2':list2, 'c':c, 'cat':cat})
```

Line on which i am getting error:

```
a = main.objects.get(unq_id = obj)
```

Models.py:

```
class main(models.Model):
    unq_id     = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    email      = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    password   = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    dob        = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    phone      = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    status     = models.CharField(max_length = 12, default = 'active')

    def verify_password(self, raw_password):
        return pbkdf2_sha256.verify(raw_password, self.password)

class Expert(models.Model):                                                                             
        unq_id  = models.OneToOneField(main, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)
        cat     = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        aop     = models.CharField(max_length=500)                                       
        exp     = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        firm    = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        Loc     = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        qualification = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='None')
        qualification1 = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='None')
        qualification2 = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='None')
        image   = ResizedImageField(default = None,upload_to= 'expert/images',size=[100, 100], quality = 100)
        e_id = models.BigIntegerField()
```

The thing I am confused about is :

```
exp = Expert.objects.all() 
    
        for objects in exp:
            testlist.append(objects.unq_id)
```

while these three lines are supposed to append unq_id of all objects of the expert model, it is rather appending the entire object... Can someone explain why it is happening so?

Thank you

Comment: `a` is simply equal to `obj`, so `a = obj`.

Comment: but obj in the for loop should be a list of unique id's

Comment: you do not get a list of unique ids, you get a list of `main` objects, note that Django will lazy load items with a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: lazy loading, never heard of it(am a newbie), but will look into it , thank you Willem!

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading

Comment: Thank you Willem , your a good man